# ADAL5 Angular, looping error in the URL instead of showing a UI when user is not AUTHORIZE (AADSTS50105)

Tags: typescript, authentication, authorization, azure-active-directory, angular5

I'm currently using `adal-angular5` and `Adal5Service` as a security authentication. The conditional access currently works when the user is not authorize however the error shows as a loop in the URL instead in the form of UI. We have already created a UI for ERROR page, however we don't know where to put the condition on where the user is not authorize which the user will go to to the ERROR page instead of loop error. Conditional Access is done via Group Assignment in Azure Active Directory side so we have no idea on how and what code/condition we will use.

Here's the code for my authentication. We are using adal.guard.ts (typescript)

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Adal5Service } from 'adal-angular5';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AdalGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private adal5Service: Adal5Service, private router: Router) {
    console.log("location below: ");
    if (location)
      console.log(location);
    else
      console.log("some falsy value");
    this.adal5Service.init({ ...environment.ssoConfig, redirectUri: location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname });
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (!environment.production)
      return true;

    this.Callback();
    if (!this.adal5Service.userInfo.authenticated) {
      this.LogIn();
      //this.router.navigate(['error/401']);
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  Callback() {
    this.adal5Service.handleWindowCallback();
  }

  LogIn() {
    this.adal5Service.login();
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code. We asumme that this is the cause of the error in loop

```js
if (!this.adal5Service.userInfo.authenticated) {
  this.LogIn();
  ...
}
```

If the user is not authenticated he/she will go to login which is correct but what if the user is not authorize? He/she will go back to login page that's why it causes the loop.

This is the display of the error that is looping in the URL:

https://oursite.net/#error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50105%3a+The+signed+in+user+is+not+assigned+to+a+role+for+the+application+%numbers-numbersthatwedontknowbut-I-think-is-confidential